# Heuristic function for solving weighted 15 puzzle

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

I am looking for a heuristic function to solve a "weighted 15 puzzle"
problem. It's the same as "15 puzzle" only i'm looking for the minimal
path to 1-15 ([Link](https://neos-guide.org/content/15puzzle)) when each "switch" costs as the piece we're moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Heuristic evaluation function for a weighted 15 puzzle:**

```
i - The element.  
MD(i) - Manhattan distance to the destination from the position of (i).
```

[image]